# Calling an Instance Method of an Interface Directly

Tags: java, oop, interface, instance

I am new to Java. Started a couple of weeks ago, relying on oracle documentation and this site. Gradually I am getting good understanding of OOP main concepts.

It is clear to me that an instance method of an interface becomes an instance method of the implementing class, and thus, can be called through an object of the implementing class, after being instantiated.

The interface Set has the method iterator(). To my understanding, we need to have a class that implements the Set interface first, then instantiate an object of that class, in order to be able to call that method (through the object).

Looking at the following code snippet, that I was reading online, I noticed that the iterator() method is called through (set) which is of the type (Set interface) only, (i.e set is not an instance of any class that implements Set interface).

My question is: is this possible?

On the other hand, regardless of whether the above is possible or not, according to oracle documentation, the method iterator() is categorized as an "instance" and "abstract" method for the Set interface. So, how come it is called for the "set" variable, since only default and static interface methods have implementations ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  hmap.put(12, "Chaitanya");
  hmap.put(2, "Rahul");

  /* Display content using Iterator*/
  Set set = hmap.entrySet();
  Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     System.out.print("key is: "+ mentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
     System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how to read this:

```
Set set = hmap.entrySet();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
```

`hmap.entrySet` returns an *object* into the `set` variable that *implements* the Set interface. That means `set` implements all of the methods declared in the Set interface. It is therefore perfectly fine to call the `iterator()` method against the `set` *object*, since it is one of the methods of the Set interface.

`set` is an *object* that *implements* the `Set` interface. It is not an interface. The only interface here is `Set`.

Comment: "`set` is an _object_ that _implements_ [...]" A mis-leading statement - especially for beginners. A variable _is not_ an object. It simply _refers to_ one. The variable's type has two meanings: 1) It constrains the runtime type of the object being referred to. 2) It constrains the methods that you can call on it.

Comment: Another weird wording: "`hmap.entrySet` returns an _object_ into the `set` variable [...]". It does not return _into_ a variable. The call to `hmap.entrySet()` returns a reference to an object (which is a `Set`), and this reference is _assigned_ to the variable.

Comment: References are a bit too early when one is trying to discern the difference between classes and interfaces. You are correct in your description of  a variable type, but describing types in terms of constraints is also a bit complicated at this point, don't you think?

Comment: No, I think the best for beginners is to be as precise as possible and use the correct terms. Everything else is more confusing. Additionally, statements like "`set` is an _object_" are simply wrong.

Comment: back to watching football, I see the language lawyers are out tonight...

Comment: There are technically no reference or value semantics in Java, yes everything is a pointer under the covers, but for all practical purposes there are no difference. Maybe when Java has pass by value or pass by reference,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Set set ; 
Here, set is only a reference variable.

If we have an interface say,'interface1', then the following would not be allowed:

interface1 object=new interface1();

But if Class1 implements interface1, then

interface1 ref=new Class1() and

Class1 ref=new Class1(),

both the above 'ref',can be used.

Also, you must know that, **all** methods of an interface are public and abstract by **default** and all abstract methods **must** be implemented.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on your last paragraph. What I know is that starting in SE8, interface default and static methods DO have implementations (not abstract). Back to the code above, the iterator() method DOES work well, while not overridden.